# How to receive values from a form?

Tags: java, ajax, forms, jsp, struts2

Hi How can I receive a value from the form on my JSP page? what to do ? the JSP has a form once the user click on submit the values of form should be sent to java class but the java class does not receive the values. the attribute of JSP is lowercase (value) and the variable of Java class is upper case. (Value)

```
   <div id=“Myform">
     <s:form action=“inputs">
         <s:textfield name=“value" label=“input:"/>
         <s:submit/>
     </s:form>
   </div>

   <sx:div>
      <div id=“Values">
        <div id=“Value”>Value is:${myClass.value}</div>
        <s:form action=“SubmitValue" >
          <s:submit/>  //When I click on this one, it does not send the value to class
        </s:form>
  </sx:div>


  private String value;

  public void Values(){
    System.out.println(“Value” + this.value);
  }
```

I have generated the getter and setters using Eclipse.

Comment: I guess you don't know the whole world behind a jsp, right??(Web Container, J2ee, servlet, etc....)

Comment: @Ging3r, yes I am new to JSP however I found another guy who has the similar problem.

Comment: So, i suggest you a tutorial, something like this: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnadr.html, because it is not easy world...good luck ; )!

Comment: Those curly doublequotes are totally wrong. Are you also using them in your real code? They have to be straight doublequotes.

Comment: If you are trying to use Struts 2 to submit and process form data, here is the struts 2 tutorial.  I suggest following this tutorial step by step. http://struts.apache.org/2.3.4.1/docs/using-struts-2-tags.html

Answer (score 0):

You have to submit something from you form to have something in your action. Have a look http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp.

If you have action with property `name` and this property is set with some value e.g. `Smit` then, in jsp you can use `<s:property/>` tag to display this value and hidden field to submit this value back to the action.

```
<sx:div>
  <div id=“Values">
    <div id=“Value”>Value is:<s:property value="name"/></div>
    <s:form action=“SubmitValue" >
      <s:hidden name="name"/>
      <s:submit/>  //When I click on this one, it does not send the value to class
    </s:form>
</sx:div>
```

Comment: Have you put something there?

Comment: I used both value, my class.value, but they do not work, from the other posts I found out that just the text box works but it should not be text box it should be a label or a div tag,

Comment: Edited my answer. If that does not help you, then try to explain a bit more, what you trying to achive.

Comment: Try this instead:
`<sx:div>
  <div id=“Values">
    <div id=“Value”>Value is:${value}</div>
    <s:form action=“SubmitValue" >
      <s:hidden name="value" value="%{value}"/>
      <s:submit/>
    </s:form>
</sx:div>`

Comment: @didiez, I did it but the value is still empty.